# How can I connect modules?

Tags: c++, makefile, gtk, configure

So, I am trying to write Makefile.am that will check the source code and the dependencies for the build.

configure.in

```
AC_PREREQ([2.68])
AC_INIT([hello], [1.0], [basinbug at yahoo.com])
AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([src/hello.cpp])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE

AC_PROG_CXX

PKG_CHECK_MODULES([GTK], [gtk+-2.0 >= 2.10])

AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile src/Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

src/Makefile.am

```
bin_PROGRAMS = hello

hello_CFLAGS = $(GTK_CFLAGS)
hello_LDFLAGS = $(GTK_LIBS)

hello_SOURCES = hello.cpp
```

what happens when i run "make"

```
Making all in src
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/maza/123/src'
g++ -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"hello\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"hello\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"1.0\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"hello\ 1.0\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"basinbug\ at\ yahoo.com\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DPACKAGE=\"hello\" -DVERSION=\"1.0\" -I.     -g -O2 -MT hello.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/hello.Tpo -c -o hello.o hello.cpp
hello.cpp:2:21: fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [hello.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/maza/123/src'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

If I'm going as AC_PROG_CC, they are used for compile the string, through AC_PROG_CXX it is not used

Comment: You saw your configure script checking for GTK+ and finding it? What value do those `GTK_*` variables have in the generated `Makefile`?

Comment: GTK_CFLAGS = -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include ... 

GTK_LIBS = -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 ....

Comment: Those aren't being used on the compilation line. That's the problem. But I don't know why. I would think the `hello_CFLAGS` line would do that.

Comment: If I'm going as AC_PROG_CC, they are used for compile the string, through AC_PROG_CXX it is not used

Comment: Makes sense. You probably need `hello_CXXFLAGS` then for `C++`.

Comment: You should use `CPPFLAGS` for includes, not `CFLAGS` or `CXXFLAGS`. (CPP = C PreProcessor, which applies to both C and C++ and is the thing that actually processes `#include` directives.)

Answer (score 0):

You are telling the autotools that your project is a C++ project (with `AC_PROG_CXX`) but you are then setting a C flag variable (`hello_CFLAGS`).

The matching variable for C++ is `hello_CXXFLAGS`.

That being said neither of those is the correct flag to use for this usage. The correct flag (thanks ptomato) is [`hello_CPPFLAGS`](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Program-Variables.html#index-CPPFLAGS).